# In next.js14, even if I surround the folder name with () to configure multiple layouts, it does not work

Tags: layout, next.js13, next.js14

I'm currently using Next.js14.

There is a Header component in root layout.tsx, but I want to prevent the header component from being rendered on the /register page.

So, even though I created a layout.tsx for the register page by wrapping the folder name with (register), the NotFound page appears.

The register path dynamically receives the searchParams value.

What is the problem?

- RootLayout.tsx

```js
export default async function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Card>
          <Header/>
         {children}
        </Card>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

- register Page RootLayout.tsx

```js
import '../globals.css';

export default function RegisterLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

- register Page.tsx

```js
export default async function RegisterPage({ searchParams }: SearchParamsType) {
  if (Object.keys(searchParams).length === 0) {
    return <NotFound />;
  }
  const encryptedCode = getEncryptedCodeFromParams({ searchParams });


  return (
    <>
      <div>content</div>
    </>
  );
```

- folder structure

[image]